# MVC Routing constrain random a-zA-Z

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I like to create register a route like these:

`User/{^[a-zA-Z]+$}/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

That's how the URL should look like :

`/User/myUser/Product/Action`

So i register a route in the AreaRegistration. The constraint should only allow words.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Customer_Default",
    "User/{^[a-zA-Z]+$}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

1. Is my constraint correct.
2. How redirect to this with `RedirectToAction` route?
3. What is the best way to get the username in the Action? Regex...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilise the `constraints` parameter of `MapRoute()`

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Customer_Default",
    "User/{username}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { username= @"^[a-zA-Z]+$" }
);
```

Then your action would be like so:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string username, int id)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the right way to use constraint is:
   routes.MapRoute(name: "Customer_Default",
               url: "User/{username}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
               constraints: new { username = "^[a-zA-Z]+$" });
2. I don't know how to redirect to this route..
3. I think you'd better create a login model, and use consistent type to pass username and password.